# How to prevent Vim from jumping to next line, when auto-completing words using `C-P`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, vi

When auto-completing words in Vim using `C-P` and pressing `Enter` to select the first candidate, without first using the arrow-keys to select between candidates, Vim will jump the cursor to the next line.

Conversely, if I first use the arrow-keys to select between candidates, Vim won't jump to the next line.

How can I prevent Vim from jumping to the next line, when selecting first candidate using Vim's auto-completion feature `C-P`?

[image]

Comment: I guess pressing Enter inserts a line break. What if you just continue typing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When popup (completion) menu is active, you're supposed to use `<C-N> <C-P> <C-E> <C-Y>` **instead of** `<Down> <Up> <Esc> <CR>` respectively (note that all these keys behave a little differently). But if you really like it you can use a mapping:

```
inoremap <expr><CR> pumvisible() ? "\<C-Y>" : "\<CR>"
```

See also [Improve completion popup menu](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Improve_completion_popup_menu) Vim tip.